Find a sequence of real-valued nonnegative functions $f_n$ on $[0,1]$ such that lim sup is infinite, but limit of the integral is $0$
Context: I am looking for a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\lim \sup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\text{d}x=0$$
Attempt: I'm looking at defining $f_n$ as a multiple of a characteristic functions, I am having a hard time meeting the conditions. I have looked at $f_n = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$ and $f_n = n^2  \chi_{[0,1/n]}$. But none of those work.
Any help or guidance in defining this function is appreciated

Hey @helpmewmath. It is customary to accept helpful answers. Please feel free to leave more comments on my answer if you still have any concerns with it.

Let $n=2^k+m$, where $k,m$ are nonnegative integers uniquely determined by the requirements that $2^k \le n < 2^{k+1}$ and $0\le m<2^k$. Define
$$
f_n = k\chi_{[\frac{m}{2^k},\frac{m+1}{2^k}]}.
$$
It is clear that the integral of $f_n$ over $[0,1]$ is $k/2^k$, which goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. It is also easy to see that for every $x\in[0,1]$, and every $M>0$, there are nonnegative integers $k,m$ such that $k>M$ and $m\le 2^k x \le m+1$ (when $2^k x$ is an integer, there are two options for $m$, and it is chosen such that $0\le m<2^k$). Then $f_n(x)>M$.

OP wants the limit of the integrals to be $0$, not $1$. But this is easy to fix: just multiply by $k$ instead of $2^k$.

Yep, I misread the question. Edited it exactly as you suggested.

Im still a little confused on how this shows that limsup fn = infinity. Could you explain more please? @Pranay

Can you be a bit more specific on what’s confusing you? I showed that for every $x$, and every large positive real $M$, there is an $n$ such that $f_n(x)>M$, which means there’s no upper bound on the set ${f_n(x):n\in \mathbb Z_+}$.
